# Print a Pdf file on the Android Button Click

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I have a pdf file in my sd card i want to print that file on the button click.
In this [document](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) it tells only how to print a custom content by rendering it on a PDF canvas and sending thus created PDF document for printing. But has no information about how to print a pdf file directly from sd card?
Please anybody has any idea how to handle this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this document which explains how to print a particular doc, image etc.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

It even contains a link for the sample and a tutorial video to achieve the same.

Comment: i had already gone through this site and also mention in my question but unable to print the pdf from sd card location